# Why does this function not return the variable after evaluating it?

Tags: javascript

Can somebody explain to me why a is not 8. I know that a = 7 after the code has run, but how do I make the function return so that it will be 8 ? New at java Script.

Can anybody explain this to me ?

```
var a = 5;
function foo(a)
{
    a++;
}

a += 2;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: there are two `a` on that page; one local, one global. you change the local, but the global stays the same. readup on passing byref vs byval, and know that all primitives (bool,str,num,etc) are passed byVal in JS. also, (5+1+2)==8, not 12....

Comment: I'm not sure where the 12 comes from - even if the function did run, it would only make it 8...

Comment: Why would you expect the function to execute if you never call it?...

Comment: where are you calling the function from? What actually do you want here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you create a function, but you don't call it. It won't run automatically, the way you created it.

As someone mentioned, you have 2 different 'a' variables. One exists inside the function, and one outside. Consider them to be two completely different things.

```
var a = 5;
function foo(a)
{
    a++; //This adds just 1 to a. If you want to add more, you can do a = a + 2; or whatever
    return a; //Whenever you call this function, it will return a
}
a = foo(a);  //Take the current a (which is 5) pass it to foo(). Assign the resulting returned value to a. 
a += 2;  //add 2 to a. 
console.log(a);
```

That code will yield an a = 8. Starts at 5, adds 1, adds 2.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/revg819p/1/

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand this

Answer (score 0):

Your function `foo(a)` is not executed. And your code is semantically equal to:

```
var a = 5;
a += 2;
console.log(a);

function foo(a) {
    a++;
}
```

Moreover, calling function `foo(a)` won't change the state of global variable `a`